# How to group duplicate strings in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, profile, group

I am new to R and struggling with grouping my dataset. This is an example of the data:

| sample | profile |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A,B |
| 3 | A,B |
| 4 | A,C |
| 5 | C |
| 6 | A,C |

I am trying to group the profiles so that the same profiles are labelled as the same group:

| sample | profile | profile group/cluster |
| --- | --- | --- |
| genome 1 | A | 1 |
| genome 2 | A,B | 2 |
| genome 3 | A,B | 2 |
| genome 4 | A,C | 3 |
| genome 5 | C | 4 |
| genome 6 | A,C | 3 |

From this, profiles A,B and A,C have been grouped together.

I have tried playing around with these packages

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(stringr)

dupes <- get_dupes(database, profile)
dupes


ll_by_outcome <- as.data.frame(database %>% 
  group_by(profile) %>% 
    add_count())
ll_by_outcome
```

But these just find duplicates within the sample. I am not sure how to go about this issue. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We could use `match`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(group = match(profile, unique(profile)), 
     sample = str_c('genome ', sample))
```

-output

```
     sample profile group
1 genome 1       A     1
2 genome 2     A,B     2
3 genome 3     A,B     2
4 genome 4     A,C     3
5 genome 5       C     4
6 genome 6     A,C     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(sample = 1:6, profile = c("A", "A,B", "A,B", "A,C", 
"C", "A,C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using factors.

With the data from @akrun's answer:

```
df1 %>% mutate(cluster = as.numeric(factor(profile)))
```

Comment: @akrun, I don't think `levels` are necessary here. By default, the levels are sorted unique categories. If you set the levels by `unique` they can be unsorted. So, depends on OP's preference. Not sure if it adds anything to the speed.

Comment: You are right.  I was thinking if it should be a custom order.  rolled back to your version

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(sample = str_c('genome', sample, sep = ' ')) %>% group_by(profile) %>% mutate(cluster = cur_group_id())
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   profile [4]
  sample   profile cluster
  <chr>    <chr>     <int>
1 genome 1 A             1
2 genome 2 A,B           2
3 genome 3 A,B           2
4 genome 4 A,C           3
5 genome 5 C             4
6 genome 6 A,C           3
```